# sass nesting doesn't work as I thought it did

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am trying to learn how to use Sass and I can't seem to get nesting down. Can someone explain to me what I am getting wrong. This is a real beginners issue I know but I can't understand what it is I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;

  header__logo {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="header">
  <img
    className="header__logo"
    src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG11.png"
    alt="amazon_logo"
   />

  <div className="header__search">
    <input className="header__searchInput" type="text" />
    <SearchIcon />
  </div>
  <div className="header__nav">
    <div className="header__boxes">
      <span className="header__boxesFirstLine">hello</span>
      <span className="header__boxesSecondLine">sign in</span>
    </div>
    <div className="header__boxes">
      <span className="header__boxesFirstLine">returns</span>
      <span className="header__boxesSecondLine">& orders</span>
    </div>
    <div className="header__boxes">
      <span className="header__boxesFirstLine">your</span>
      <span className="header__boxesSecondLine">prime</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was under the impression that in order to style the header img, which has a class of header__logo I could nest it within my sass file in the .header brackets but this is obviously wrong because it doesn't show up in the generated App.css file and isn't their in the developer tools.

Sorry I know this is a noob question.

Comment: you miss a `.` before header__logo  (`.header__logo `)

Comment: It's a typo, you forgot to add the `.` to denote a class name `header__logo {
    width: 100px;
  }` should be `.header__logo { ]`

Comment: Voting to close because it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding a quick answer, even though this is a typo (missing the `.` for the class name`), but since you're learning.

Since all of your children elements are using BEM style for the class names, you can reference the parent element using `&`:

```
.header {
  
  /* set the parent as a variable to reference for grandchildren */  
  $p : &;
    
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;

  &__nav {
      /* styles */
      
      #{$p}__boxes {
          /* styles */
      }
  } 

  &__logo {
    width: 100px;
  }

  &__search {
      /* styles*/
 
  }

  &__boxes {
      /* styles*/
 }

}
```

This will compile to:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__nav {
  /* styles */
}
.header__nav .header__boxes {
  /* styles */
}
.header__logo {
  width: 100px;
}
.header__search {
  /* styles*/
}
.header__boxes {
  /* styles*/
}
```

Comment: Damn...... yeah now I remember. Thanks for not downvoting I knew it was something really simple. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MarkScholes I updated the SCSS a bit to include a variable to hold the parent element so you can use it on grandchildren elements, e.g `header__boxes` since they are children of the `nav` class.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "/* set the parent as a variable to reference for grandchildren */  
  $p : &;"

Comment: Basically, `&` refers to the direct parent. So, `&__element` will compile to `.parentclass__element`, however, for children of `&__element`, if you used `&__child` it would compile to `.parentclass__element__child`, but in your markup you are using `header__element` for grandchildren. So what you do, is set the `&` to a variable to always reference the top level element. So no matter how nested you get `#{$p}` will always reference `.header`.

Comment: Look at the `__nav` and `__boxes` portion of the code to see.

Comment: okay cool, yeah that makes sense i'd just never seen "$p : &;" before

Comment: right on. `$p` could be any variable you want. I used that as a shorthand for `parent`. It's super helpful in situations like yours.